# Javascript: однострочное обращение к членам синглтона

Tags: javascript, typescript, шаблоны-проектирования

Создал базовый класс - синглтон:

```
class ISingleton
{
    static _instance: ISingleton;

    constructor() {
        if (ISingleton._instance)
            return ISingleton._instance;

            ISingleton._instance = this;            
    }
}

export class IEnvironment extends ISingleton
{
    @observable ui: any = {}

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

и его использование выглядит так:

```
const environment: IEnvironment = new IEnvironment();
func(environment.ui)
```

Подскажите можно ли его переделать так, чтобы можно было выполнять однострочные обращения к членам класса без `new`:

```
func(IEnvironment.getInstance().ui)
```

т.е. что-то на подобии работы со стандартным `Object`

Вообще привык что в том же C++ конструктор объявляется приватным и делается статический публичный метод `getInstance()`, который уже и создает объект синглтона

Можно ли такое же проделать в javascript?

А то реально нужно лишь однострочное обращение к члену синглтона, а приходится делать 2 строчную запись, да и лишняя для пользователя класса логика этот `new` как по мне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В TypeScript можно объявить конструктор приватным. Но нужно понимать, что на уровне JS все эти финтифлюшки будут проигнорированы.

Но раз вам нужно наследование, то лучше объявить конструктор `protected` и проверять экземпляр в конкретном классе, а не по всей цепочке наследования.

```
class Base {
    protected constructor() {}

    protected name: string = 'base';

    say() {
        console.log(`hi from ${this.name}!`);
    }

    private static _instance: Base;

    static getInstance() {
        if (!this.hasOwnProperty('_instance')) {
            this._instance = new this;
        }
        return this._instance;
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    name = 'child';
}

const c1 = Child.getInstance();
const c2 = Child.getInstance();
console.log(c1 === c2); // true
const b = Base.getInstance(); 
console.log(c1 === b); // false
b.say(); // hi from base!
c1.say(); // hi from child!
```

https://tsplay.dev/weelYw

Comment: я не спорю, что финтифлюшки, мне в первую очередь интересую такой подход, который полностью исключит использование `new` вне класса `X`

Comment: в таком подходе наследование не работает толком почему-то :( как бы это исправить - т.е. `getInstance()` выдает базовый класс, а не наследника

Comment: @Zhihar переделал

Comment: это конечно работает, но приходится вводить дополнительную переменную `name`! Хотя учитывая какие классы-обертки в js, то может по другому нельзя

Comment: @Zhihar ну тут `name` исключительно для примера, что бы показать что возвращаются экземпляры разных классов и у них есть свои независимые данные.

Comment: 1)`console.log((new class A { }).constructor.name)` 2) `getInstance` почему не геттером 4) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ0PQA4CcCWAbmAC5ITEl7DQD6AkgHblgPAIBcciA3Ops8SrQA5gmLRGzVggAUAShR9MmPADNoMgITEAFnggA6HZADyAdwYAFHAHssCHMQCeMgOT0mFaa7kLk0XX0DDyk2aABeaAYEMwC9GABfJWVoHDEAVxwGOKCQrzZkpOVcG1JgUgATaGAbTxx08psceRRoIv4wFz9q2ogbEAQDEBthGQADPWhVWwBbaAASZEDDGrqG4iaDBjAZhATNMYUkpNBIGABhPRAqhAAPUgYKmHgIJH8k1FW+gaGRmUu8NcDJJ8khwuDoACgSCWGw5NxoAB6REBeoIT69fqDYajF6DGHSCIQqEVYGeWEIeFIlGqMAgV6oPFk0KDCCdeQI5HQSbTGxzABGiE0qBJzNBBjZXU5KJ5s2qVwqmiAA